# SQL - Retrieving auto-increment value after inserting a custom value

Tags: database, sqlite

Say I need to keep track of the s.no's of students. They are assigned a s.no based on auto-increment. 1st person gets 1,2nd person gets 2,so on. But if a student wants a custom s.no (say 32) i need to assign him 32 and when the next person comes i need to assign him 3 and next person 4 and so on. I will check through database before assigning custom serial number to make sure they don't exist already. I'm using sqlite3. I have a db table with 1 column (auto-increment pk)

Database :-

```
S.no
    1
    2
    3
```

Now i insert a custom-value "32"

```
custom = 32
    con.execute("INSERT INTO table (id) values (?)", (custom)
```

Database :

```
S.no
    1
    2
    3
    32
```

Now when i use auto-increment to add value the database becomes :

```
S.no
    1
    2
    3
    32
    33
    34
```

What i want it to be :

```
S.no
    1
    2
    3
    32
    4
    5
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not how [SQLite's autoincrement algorithm](http://www.sqlite.org/autoinc.html) works.

To get autoincrementing IDs that are smaller than the largest actually used ID, you have to implement the algorithm yourself (i.e., store the current counter value somewhere else).

Comment: which also might require transactions, if there are multiple users/processes inserting rows (and ids).

Comment: So i must store a variable say "k" and k+=1 it every time i store and ignore when a custom s.no is added. Will work it out. Thanks !